# after using glBlendEquationOES(GL_MAX_EXT) how can i disable it?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

im trying to draw a glowing texture and after reading this post:
[Opengl ES 1.x glowing effect in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678558/opengl-es-1-x-glowing-effect-in-ios).
I have used this glBlendEquationOES(GL_MAX_EXT) command which makes the effect i wanted but the problem is it makes everything else corrupted.
i wonder how can i disable glBlendEquationOES(GL_MAX_EXT) after i use it? or return it to default mode?
Thanks!
Guy.

Comment: You can `glDisable(GL_BLEND)` it. I think it defaults to `GL_FUNC_ADD`; didn't find this info anywhere, though.

Answer (score 0):

You disable blending by... disabling blending. You enabled blending by calling `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`. So turning it off means calling `glDisable(GL_BLEND)`.

The blend equation/funcs can remain as you want. You don't have to set them to default or to any particular value. Disabling blending means that their values are irrelevant.

Comment: I forgot to mention that im using cocos2d engine and by calling glDisable(GL_BLEND) it messed up the drawing made by cocos2d, stuff like CCSPrite and CCParticles, i used stefan solution and found that GL_FUNC_ADD_OES value is the "default" value for glBlendEquationOES. thank you all for the help, i have only basic opengl knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving and restoring the graphics state?

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);

// graphics state corrupting code ...

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```