# cocos3d line glow effect

Tags: glow, cocos3d

I'm using cocos3d 7.0 (that is, a 3d extension for cocos2d) on iOS 3.1 which has only GLES 1.1.

I want to draw a line in space with a glowing effect. Ideally, it has to look like a line on the second image in [Opengl ES 1.x glowing effect in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678558/opengl-es-1-x-glowing-effect-in-ios). But the above example uses plain gl calls, and no cocos3d/2d framework calls.

Is there any good example or tutorial of creating such an effect in terms of cocos3d api?